# Using RabbitMQ RESTful services with Angular2

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, rabbitmq

I am currently developing a project where I need to have access to all Queues that are connected to a determined Rabbitmq. To do so, I was trying to get this information using rabbitmq's RESTful services. I tried to do some example using POSTman, like sending a request to localhost:15672/api/connections with guest:guest as username and password, and everything worked fine; However, when I tried to send the same request using my project on Angular the following error message appeared:

> zone.js:2177 XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:15672/api/overview. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I made some research about this error and all the solutions that I could find suggested that I should allow my browser on Chrome to make CORS requests, but this solution would require that I changed every browser that would run my project, which would not be effective. Anyone knows another way that I could get Rabbitmq's information using an Angular 2 application?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Also, if I add "http://" at the start of the request, the error message changes to:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:15672/api/overview. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
@Injectable()
export class RabbitHttp {

protected headers: Headers;

constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router,
    public globalService: GlobalService
) {
}
  public get(url: string, parameters: any): Promise<Response> {
    url = "http://" + url;
    this.setDefaultHeaders(parameters, url);
    return this.http.get(url, { headers: this.headers }).toPromise();
};
private setDefaultHeaders(data: any,  url: string): void {
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    this.headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + data);
    this.headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", url);
}
}
```

The rabbit service is started with its 6 default plugins that you enable with the command

> rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

As for the url and the parameters, the url received in the function is localhost:15672/api/overview and the parameters is guest:guest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in [this code](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/blob/master/src/rabbit_mgmt_cors.erl#L25-L42) that CORS headers *are* returned when the request contains an `Origin` header (`match_origin` function).

The requests you create with Angular must contain an `Origin` header.

Comment: It does contain, The header of my application is defined as follow:
        
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", url);
        this.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        this.headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + data);

Comment: The header must be named "Origin" - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/blob/master/src/rabbit_mgmt_cors.erl#L72-L93

If you can provide code that reproduces this issue, fixing it will go much faster. I can only guess at what you are doing incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks =), just edited my original post with the code that I am currently using.

Comment: Change this:

this.headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", url);

To this:

this.headers.append("Origin", url);

Comment: @FilipeTabosa - if my response is correct, please mark this question as answered. If it did not work, please provide a complete set of code I can use to reproduce your issue and fix it.

Comment: Sorry for not answering before, I was kinda busy last week so I did not have time to give it a try. I could not acess it using the Origin as mentioned because I got the following error: Refused to set unsafe header "Origin", but thanks for the help, I just marked your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: So I managed to make it work, here is the solution. The first problem was really obvious and I did not use it before due to my lack of knowledge on rabbit. It has to have the following line on the rabbitmq.config file: 
 "[
  {rabbitmq_management,
    [{cors_allow_origins, ["*"]}]}
].
"

Comment: But, even with this line, I was not managing to make it work, and the reason for that was because I was using rabbitMQ version 3.6.0, which has a bug that does not allow some type of requisitions, like for instance OPTIONS ones. So I had to change it to the latest version, which is 3.6.10, and with that I managed to make it work. Once again thanks for your help and assistance =), have a great day.